# Applying certificate using .pem, .cert, .p7b files

Tags: ssl, https, jboss, certificate

i've been assigned to enable HTTPS for one of the servers domain. I am familiar with the standard generate jks file to generate csr and lastly i will be given the p7b file. However the IT for the server already given me the certificate which is as below:-

1. d1668d336843ba22.crt
2. gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b
3. d1668d336843ba22.pem

My aim is to produce a .p12 file as the to keystore for configuration in standalone.xml

"<ssl>
<keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
</ssl>"

I have run the following command to attach the certificate to the keystore but it produce error:

command:

keytool -importcert -alias ecclims.eagle-cement.com.ph -file E:\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone_lv84\configuration\Cert2020\d1668d336843ba22.crt -keystore E:\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone_lv84\configuration\Cert2020\d1668d336843ba22.pem -trustcacerts

Error: Invalid Keystore format

Anybody please guide me through this..

Answer (score 0):

Convert the files to PKCS#12/PFX file using OpenSSL:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ".\output.pfx" -inkey ".\d1668d336843ba22.pem" -in ".\d1668d336843ba22.cer" -passout "pass:12345678"
```